# Graphs without cycles of length >3 as subgraphs

Tags: graph-theory

Let a graph contains no cycles of length greater than $3$ as subgraphs. In other words, each its cycle of length greater than $3$ has an extra edge (off the edges of the cycle).

Is it true that there is a vertex $v$ such that for each two edges $vu$ and $vw$ it holds that $uw$ is an edge as well?

Comment: Your "extra edge (off the edges of the cycle)" seems to change the definition of the length of a cycle. For us to help you will have to [edit] the question to clarify. Give us some examples. Don't respond in comments.

Answer (score 0):

No, a counter-example being a tree.

Comment: In a tree, any leaf vertex $v$ will have the desired property (vacuously). In a counterexample graph, each vertex would have two (distinct) neighbors which are not adjacent to each other.

Comment: I think you can easily imagine a tree with such vertices.